# converting object[] to an entity type through iterating

Tags: java

I have  a pojo of type

```
 public class Comain implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private Integer ComainId;

    private String name;

    private String Cescription;


     private boolean  isAvailable ;
     }
```

Below is the piece of code through which I am extracting the results

```
   List<Object[]>  d = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
   d = ARepository.getAb();
```

upon debugging I have analyzed that I am getting the result in the below format

```
 d = {ArrayList}
    > o = {object[4]}
       > o = {Integer}1
       > 1 = "qqq"
       > 2 = "ddddd"
       > 3 = {Boolean} false
     > 1 = {object[4]}
       > o = {Integer}2
       > 1 = "qrtq"
       > 2 = "rrddd"
       > 3 = {Boolean} true
```

now I want to typecast the object[] array  into pojo type that is Comain pojo now please advise how to achieve the same although I have created the object type Comain

```
   Comain C = new Comain ()
```

[image: debug image]

Answer (score 1):

**If the order of the object array is fix** then you can go through the array and use the corresponding indexes.

```java
List<Comain> comains = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object[] objects : d) {
    comains.add(new Comain((Integer) objects[0], (String) objects[1], (String) objects[2], (Boolean) objects[3]));
}
```

Of course you have to add a constructor for the `Comain` class.

```java
public Comain(Integer comainId, String name, String cescription, boolean isAvailable) {
    this.ComainId = comainId;
    this.name = name;
    this.Cescription = cescription;
    this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
}
```

Comment: @Rahin In this above example we are not iterating over list first we have to iterate over the list

Comment: Sorry, you are right, you don't need the inner for loop. Check my edited answer.

Comment: @Rashin still the answer is not correct the Object array is inside the list please check the image attached

Comment: Yes, and the `for (Object[] objects : d) {` loop will go through the list. This is equivalent to `for(int i=0; i<d.size(); i++) { comains.add(new Comain((Integer) d.get(i)[0], (String) d.get(i)[1], (String) d.get(i)[2], (Boolean) d.get(i)[3])); }`